# RelayCommand not binding my object in the MainViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm-light, relaycommand

Hello I'm new here and I'm trying to explain my problem in a good english because it's not my mother tongue :)
So I'm using MVVM Light and I have my RelayCommand :

```
private RelayCommand _SearchMethod;
 public RelayCommand SearchMethod
    {

        get
        {
            return _SearchMethod = _SearchMethod ?? new RelayCommand(GetDataMethod, CanSearchMethod);

        }

    }
```

And in my GetDataMethod , I retrieve some values that I put in the Record Object . I use try catch because sometimes valueMax1 or valueMax2 have values and sometimes not but when they don't , I put 00.00 .

See below :

```
public void GetDataMethod() {

        var filtre = Rec.Where(y => y.Date.Contains(SelectedItemCombo1) && y.ID == SelectedItemCombo2.ID).Take(22).ToList();
        var filtre2 = Rec2.Where(y => y.Date.Contains(SelectedItemCombo1) && y.ID == SelectedItemCombo2.ID).Take(22).ToList();             
        var valueMax1 = (double)0;
        var valueMax2 = (double)0;



        try {
                valueMax1 = filtre.Where(x => x.Unite == "MWh" || x.Unite == "kWh" && x.Valeur != "0").
              TakeWhile(y => !y.Valeur.Contains(dateConsommation[1]))
              .Max(y => double.Parse(y.Valeur, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pas de valeur pour l'année écoulée");
            valueMax1 = 00.00;

        }finally {

            try
            {

                var filtre3 = filtre2.SkipWhile(y => !y.Valeur.Contains(dateConsommation[1])).Where(x => x.Unite == "MWh" || x.Unite == "kWh").ToList();
                valueMax2 = filtre3.Max(y => double.Parse(y.Valeur, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pas de valeur pour l'année précédente");
                valueMax2 = 00.00;
            }
            finally {
                if (Record == null)
                {
                    Record = new FilteredRecord()
                    {
                        Date = SelectedItemCombo1,
                        ID = SelectedItemCombo2.ID,
                        Value1 = (valueMax1 == 00.00) ? 00.00 : valueMax1,
                        Value2 = (valueMax2 == 00.00) ? 00.00 : valueMax2,
                        Value3 = valueMax1 - valueMax2
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    Record.Date = SelectedItemCombo1;
                    Record.ID = SelectedItemCombo2.ID;
                    Record.Value1 = (valueMax1 == 00.00) ? 00.00 : valueMax1;
                    Record.Value2 = (valueMax2 == 00.00) ? 00.00 : valueMax2;
                    Record.Value3 = valueMax1 - valueMax2;
                }

            }

        }





    }
```

My Record has the values that I want .

My question is : Why in the MainWindow.xaml the binding is not working ??? Because before using RelayCommand , the binding worked !!

My code in the MainWindow.xaml :

```
 <Window x:Class="JackAndJayLight.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="435" Width="435"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JackAndJayLight"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">  

 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Margin="0 2 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Record.ID}" />
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Margin="0 2 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Record.Date}" />
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Margin="0 2 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Record.Value1}" />
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Margin="0 2 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Record.Value2}" />
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Margin="0 2 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Record.Value3}" />
                </StackPanel>
```

My declaration of the object Record:

```
public FilteredRecord Record { get; private set; }
```

If you can help me ... Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `FilteredRecord` class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @RohitVats  Yes my class is like this :

    public class FilteredRecord : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject
    {}

Comment: If `Record` is null, you are initializing it to new value. Make sure class where this command is declared also implements INPC.

Comment: @RohitVats  Yes because before using RelayCommand the binding worked , my class MainViewModel is like this : public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase  and ViewModelBase herites of ObservableObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `RaisePropertyChanged` event to notify UI that some property has changed. In your case you need to notify for `Record` property. Change property syntax to this and see if that helps:

```
private FilteredRecord record;
public FilteredRecord Record
{
  get
  {
     return record;
  }
  private set
  {
     if(record != value)
     {
        record = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Record");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand before it worked without it but now I won't forget for my next projects , thanks again ;)